# Debug Xamarin Forms Android Application

Tags: android, forms, xamarin

I can debug the android application on Visual Studio Emulator that works fine  . But each time i change something in the application the deployed application does not reflect it , i have to uninstall the application from the emulator first then deploy again . So the changes do not show in the emulator unless i uninstall from the emulator and redeploy ,   Is there a way around this ?

Comment: [Xamarin Live Player](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/live/)

Comment: I don't  have a device capable of running the live player app , i am sure there is a real solution to the problem .

Comment: Rebuild can't help you? Or I think maybe VS doesn't save your change. Will every App  occur the same problem? Or you can change  another simulator.

Comment: tried Clean , build , rebuild , changed version number then rebuild , and other things .

Comment: The only thing that works is uninstalling it from the emulator then deploy or just start debugger  .

Answer (score 0):

Why do you do this ? You don't have to uninstall the app from the emulator manually, you just have to rebuild your application and start it on VS selecting your target device or emulator. 
VS makes the rest for you.

Or you can go the way @Joe Lv suggested, use the [Xamarin Live Player](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/live/),
here you can see all changes on runtime.

Comment: As i said in my question , if i make a change and run the app in the emulator it still shows the old version .  Then i have to uninstall and redeploy in order for my changes to show up  .

Comment: Check the Android project's build configuration. Make sure that Fast assembly deployment is unchecked. (Project > Options > Build > Android Build > General tab).This also could solves your problem!